# Caterpillar(?) in Leaf Cocoon identification - Missouri

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

A small chunk of leaves fell off of a potted tomato plant. We noticed our cats taking an interest in it once it started moving. Then a little caterpillar poked its head out. What kind of bug is this and should we worry about our plant?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you describe its size or take a photo with something for scale?

Comment: I apologize, the bug moved shortly after I took the picture and now I can't find it. It was pretty small. The pictures above probably show about 1cm of its body poking out and the diameter of the bug is less than half a cm, I would say.

Comment: Larvae making these sort of cases out of found material is typical for Bagworm Moths (Psychidae), but I don't know what species you have in Missouri. But it's a start if you don't get an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the larvae (caterpillar) of a [**bagworm moth**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth) (family Psychidae).

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bagworm_Moth_(Psychidae)_caterpillar_(14345265279).jpg); Credit: [Bernard DUPONT](https://www.flickr.com/people/65695019@N07)</sup>

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth):

> The caterpillar larvae of the Psychidae construct cases out of silk and environmental materials such as sand, soil, lichen, or plant materials.

There are about 240 genera, so I will leave IDing to lower taxonomic levels up to you. However, based on the striations of the caterpillar and your lcoation, the [Evergreen Bagworm Moth](https://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Evergreen-Bagworm-Moth) doesn't seem like a bad guess...