# What is this insect seen in Northern Italy?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I am from Northern Italy, close to the border with Slovenia.

I saw this thing today on the window, and was sure it was a piece of a dry rosmarine branch carried there by the wind - until it started to move.

It looks like a cocoon of some kind, on the top of it there is an opening from which a head of something like a caterpillar comes out, sometimes together with some portion of its body with two (?) tiny legs on each of its body "segments". But I imagined cocoons as something attached to a branch, not moving.. While this thing moved from one point of the window to another, always attached to the window (**not** using what I think are the caterpillar's legs). (I must admit I am reluctant to open the window and examine it from a closer range :) ; the photograph is taken from inside the house).

What can this insect be? (the length is around 4-5 cm)

[image]

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to identify this chrysalis?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/55884) and [Caterpillar(?) in Leaf Cocoon identification - Missouri](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/61286).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some kind of [bagworm moth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth). Their larvae would use silk and plant debris to construct a protective case around themselves. It’s hard to tell the exact species unless you open up the case or wait for it to emerge as an adult moth.

There are species on pretty much every continent and definitely some in Northern Italy. You can check out a list of observations and photos here: https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/61415-Psychidae

Comment: As an aside, if you are interested in this kind of stuff. I highly recommend that you also join the iNaturalist community. There are many more naturalist experts of various beaches of life there to help with identification.